# List directory in Go

Tags: go

I've been trying to figure out how to simply list the files and folders in a single directory in Go.

I've found [`filepath.Walk`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk), but it goes into sub-directories automatically, which I don't want.  All of my other searches haven't turned anything better up.

I'm sure that this functionality exists, but it's been really hard to find.  Let me know if anyone knows where I should look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You can try using the [ReadDir](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadDir) function in the `os` package. Per the docs:

> ReadDir reads the named directory, returning all its directory entries sorted by filename.

The resulting slice contains `os.DirEntry` types, which provide the methods listed [here](https://pkg.go.dev/os#DirEntry). Here is a basic example that lists the name of everything in the current directory (folders are included but not specially marked - you can check if an item is a folder by using the `IsDir()` method):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
     "log"
)

func main() {
    entries, err := os.ReadDir("./")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
 
    for _, e := range entries {
            fmt.Println(e.Name())
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only want the **names** of the contents of a directory and speed is of essence, note that using [Readdirnames](https://golang.org/src/os/dir.go?s=1898:1960#L34) is *orders of magnitude* faster (around 20x faster for me)

Comment: @SquattingSlavInTracksuit: I promoted your comment here to an answer, because I didn't have comment privileges at the time. If you'd rather answer it and get the credit, LMK.

Comment: @SquattingSlavInTracksuit - that's just one order of magnitude :P

Comment: Since go 1.16, io/ioutil is deprecated. Instead of ioutil.ReadDir() you should use os.ReadDir()

Answer (score 116):

We can get a list of files inside a folder on the file system using various golang standard library functions.

1. **filepath.Walk**
2. **ioutil.ReadDir**
3. **os.File.Readdir**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    var (
        root  string
        files []string
        err   error
    )

    root := "/home/manigandan/golang/samples"
    // filepath.Walk
    files, err = FilePathWalkDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // ioutil.ReadDir
    files, err = IOReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //os.File.Readdir
    files, err = OSReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file)
    }
}
```

1. **Using filepath.Walk**

> The `path/filepath` package provides a handy way to scan all the files
>   in a directory, it will automatically scan each sub-directories in the
>   directory.

```
func FilePathWalkDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

2. **Using ioutil.ReadDir**

> `ioutil.ReadDir` reads the directory named by dirname and returns a
>   list of directory entries sorted by filename.

```
func IOReadDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    fileInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        return files, err
    }

    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        files = append(files, file.Name())
    }
    return files, nil
}
```

3. **Using os.File.Readdir**

> Readdir reads the contents of the directory associated with file and
>   returns a slice of up to n FileInfo values, as would be returned by
>   Lstat, in directory order. Subsequent calls on the same file will
>   yield further FileInfos.

```
func OSReadDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    f, err := os.Open(root)
    if err != nil {
        return files, err
    }
    fileInfo, err := f.Readdir(-1)
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return files, err
    }

    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        files = append(files, file.Name())
    }
    return files, nil
}
```

Benchmark results.

[image: benchmark score]

Get more details on this [Blog Post](https://medium.com/@manigandand/list-files-in-a-directory-using-golang-963b1df11304)

Comment: The most complete answer here. It's worth noting that there is no memory usage or allocs reported by this benchmark. It's possible the faster implementations use more memory. It's also possible that the number of CPU cores on the tester's computer hurts/helps the concurrent `filepath.Walk`. Furthermore, `filepath.Walk` supports recursive decent while `os.File.Readdir` and `ioutil.ReadDir` do not.

Comment: Could someone explain to me how to read / interpret the benchmark results?

Comment: @xuiqzy `ns/op` = nanoseconds per operation, so smaller is better. But as @xeoncross mentioned, Walk might be better in concurrent environments and might be using a lot less memory in environments with lots of files.

Comment: From Go source code for `ioutil.ReadDir`: "As of Go 1.16, `os.ReadDir` is a more efficient and correct choice: it returns a list of `fs.DirEntry` instead of `fs.FileInfo`,and it returns partial results in the case of an error midway through reading a directory."
The complete `ioutil` package functions should be replaced by functions in `io` or `os` package per documentation.

Comment: this line ` root := "/home/manigandan/golang/samples"` occurs an error because root is already declared

Answer (score 82):

Even simpler, use `path/filepath`:

```
package main    

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    files, err := filepath.Glob("*")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(files) // contains a list of all files in the current directory
}
```

Comment: Note that `Glob ignores file system errors such as I/O errors reading directories. The only possible returned error is ErrBadPattern, when pattern is malformed.`

Comment: Be sure to understand what Glob does before using it. 
https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob

Answer (score 28):

Starting with Go 1.16, you can use the [os.ReadDir](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/io/os/#ReadDir) function.

> `func ReadDir(name string) ([]DirEntry, error)`

It reads a given directory and returns a `DirEntry` slice that contains the directory entries sorted by filename.

It's an optimistic function, so that, when an error occurs while reading the directory entries, it tries to return you a slice with the filenames up to the point before the error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    files, err := os.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }
}
```

Of interest: [Go 1.17](https://twitter.com/golang/status/1403016905179422723) (Q3 2021) includes [`fs.FileInfoToDirEntry()`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/io/fs/#FileInfoToDirEntry):

> ```golang
> func FileInfoToDirEntry(info FileInfo) DirEntry
> ```
>
> `FileInfoToDirEntry` returns a `DirEntry` that returns information from `info`.
> If `info` is nil, `FileInfoToDirEntry` returns nil.

---

#### Background

Go 1.16 (Q1 2021) will propose, with [CL 243908](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/243908/7) and [CL 243914](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/243914/) , the [`ReadDir` function](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/243914/5/src/io/fs/readdir.go), based on the [`FS` interface](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/243908/7/src/io/fs/fs.go):

```golang
// An FS provides access to a hierarchical file system.
//
// The FS interface is the minimum implementation required of the file system.
// A file system may implement additional interfaces,
// such as fsutil.ReadFileFS, to provide additional or optimized functionality.
// See io/fsutil for details.
type FS interface {
    // Open opens the named file.
    //
    // When Open returns an error, it should be of type *PathError
    // with the Op field set to "open", the Path field set to name,
    // and the Err field describing the problem.
    //
    // Open should reject attempts to open names that do not satisfy
    // ValidPath(name), returning a *PathError with Err set to
    // ErrInvalid or ErrNotExist.
    Open(name string) (File, error)
}
```

That allows for ["os: add `ReadDir` method for lightweight directory reading"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41467):
See [commit a4ede9f](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/a4ede9f9a6254360d39d0f45aec133c355ac6b2a):

```golang
// ReadDir reads the contents of the directory associated with the file f
// and returns a slice of DirEntry values in directory order.
// Subsequent calls on the same file will yield later DirEntry records in the directory.
//
// If n > 0, ReadDir returns at most n DirEntry records.
// In this case, if ReadDir returns an empty slice, it will return an error explaining why.
// At the end of a directory, the error is io.EOF.
//
// If n <= 0, ReadDir returns all the DirEntry records remaining in the directory.
// When it succeeds, it returns a nil error (not io.EOF).
func (f *File) ReadDir(n int) ([]DirEntry, error) 

// A DirEntry is an entry read from a directory (using the ReadDir method).
type DirEntry interface {
    // Name returns the name of the file (or subdirectory) described by the entry.
    // This name is only the final element of the path, not the entire path.
    // For example, Name would return "hello.go" not "/home/gopher/hello.go".
    Name() string
    
    // IsDir reports whether the entry describes a subdirectory.
    IsDir() bool
    
    // Type returns the type bits for the entry.
    // The type bits are a subset of the usual FileMode bits, those returned by the FileMode.Type method.
    Type() os.FileMode
    
    // Info returns the FileInfo for the file or subdirectory described by the entry.
    // The returned FileInfo may be from the time of the original directory read
    // or from the time of the call to Info. If the file has been removed or renamed
    // since the directory read, Info may return an error satisfying errors.Is(err, ErrNotExist).
    // If the entry denotes a symbolic link, Info reports the information about the link itself,
    // not the link's target.
    Info() (FileInfo, error)
}
```

[`src/os/os_test.go#testReadDir()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a4ede9f9a6254360d39d0f45aec133c355ac6b2a/src/os/os_test.go#L364-L410) illustrates its usage:

```golang
    file, err := Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("open %q failed: %v", dir, err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    s, err2 := file.ReadDir(-1)
    if err2 != nil {
        t.Fatalf("ReadDir %q failed: %v", dir, err2)
    }
```

---

[Ben Hoyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68707/ben-hoyt) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668850/list-directory-in-go/64443904#comment116511944_64443904) to Go 1.16 [`os.ReadDir`](https://github.com/golang/go/blame/3d913a926675d8d6fcdc3cfaefd3136dfeba06e1/src/os/dir.go#L109):

> `os.ReadDir(path string) ([]os.DirEntry, error)`, which you'll be able to call directly without the `Open` dance.
> So you can probably shorten this to just `os.ReadDir`, as that's the concrete function most people will call.

See [commit 3d913a9](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/3d913a926675d8d6fcdc3cfaefd3136dfeba06e1) (Dec. 2020):

> ### `os`: add `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, `CreateTemp` (was `TempFile`), `MkdirTemp` (was `TempDir`) from `io/ioutil`
>
> `io/ioutil` was a poorly defined collection of helpers.
>
> [Proposal #40025](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40025) moved out the generic I/O helpers to io.
> This CL for [proposal #42026](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42026) moves the OS-specific helpers to `os`,
> making the entire `io/ioutil` package deprecated.

> `os.ReadDir` returns `[]DirEntry`, in contrast to `ioutil.ReadDir`'s `[]FileInfo`.
> (Providing a helper that returns `[]DirEntry` is one of the primary motivations for this change.)

Comment: Yes, though note that as part of this 1.16 work they're also adding `os.ReadDir(path string) ([]os.DirEntry, error)`, which you'll be able to call directly without the `Open` dance. So you can probably shorten this to just `os.ReadDir`, as that's the concrete function most people will call.

Comment: @BenHoyt Good point, thank you. I have included your comment, with additional documentation links, in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 23):

`ioutil.ReadDir` is a good find, but if you click and look at the source you see that it calls the method [Readdir of os.File](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir).  If you are okay with the directory order and don't need the list sorted, then this Readdir method is all you need.

Comment: (os/*File).ReadDir is not only preferred based on needing to sort the directory, it was actually made to be more efficient. *File.Readdir goes through every file in the directory and calls Lstat() (system call) to return a slice of FileInfo. Whereas, ReadDir only performs a single system call and returns a slice of DirEntry, which contains Name(), IsDir(), and Info(). Info() returns the file information and calls Lstat().

TLDR: ReadDir is lazy and Readdir is eager

Answer (score 18):

From your description, what you probably want is [os.Readdirnames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames).

> `func (f *File) Readdirnames(n int) (names []string, err error)`
>
> Readdirnames reads the contents of the directory associated with file and returns a slice of up to n names of files in the directory, in directory order. Subsequent calls on the same file will yield further names.
>
> ...
>
> If n <= 0, Readdirnames returns all the names from the directory in a single slice.

Snippet:

```
file, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer file.Close()
names, err := file.Readdirnames(0)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println(names)
```

Credit to [SquattingSlavInTracksuit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7595633/squattingslavintracksuit)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668850/list-directory-in-go#comment103102764_14668907); I'd have suggested promoting their comment to an answer if I could.

Answer (score 5):

A complete example of printing all the files in a directory recursively using `Readdirnames`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    path := "/path/to/your/directory"
    err := readDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func readDir(path string) error {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    names, _ := file.Readdirnames(0)
    for _, name := range names {
        filePath := fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v", path, name)
        file, err := os.Open(filePath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Println(filePath)
        if fileInfo.IsDir() {
            readDir(filePath)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```