# How to reference other files within a lambda function?

Tags: go, aws-lambda

In a handler of mine, I open a `.mmdb` file for doing geo lookups. In my package, I use `./` notation to reference the file since the handler and file are in the same directory. Now that I want to deploy the function using serverless, I've included the file within the `include` block in my `serverless.yml` file. Based on the package size that I'm seeing, the file is being uploaded, however I'm getting the error

```
open ./GeoLite2-City.mmdb: no such file or directory
```

when running the lambda. What is the proper way to get the location of the file from within my lambda?

Comment: AWS exports a variable called `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` which points to the source of your deployed code. You should use that as base path

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by listing the contents of the directory that I was using in my lambda, using the code found in this answer: [List directory in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668850/list-directory-in-go/14668907#14668907). After doing so I realized that I was in the root directory of the entire folder that I uploaded, not the directory of the specific package I was running the code from (containing `main.go`)